Why is there no formated numbers in the barchart segments?
I want to make a graph in SAS using SGPlot and there to be numbers in the in the barchart segments in diffrent colors depending on the type of car.
I´v tried to use an annotated dataset to print the numbers but they do not show.


proc sql;
    create table cars(where=(make < 'D')) as
    select make, type, count(*) as count 
        from sashelp.cars 
     group by make, type
     order by make, type;
quit;

data annodata;
 set cars;
    retain  x1space "datavalue" y1space "datavalue" textsize 10 function "text" width 30;
    length textcolor $20 label $5 xc1 $13;
    y1=count;
    label=put(count,2.);
    xc1=make;
    if type='SUV' then textcolor ='red';
    else if type='Sedan' then textcolor ='yellow';
    else if type='Sports' then textcolor ='red';
    else if type='Truck' then textcolor ='blue';
    else textcolor ='white';

run;

proc template;
    define statgraph barchart;
        begingraph / attrpriority=none  ; 
        layout lattice;
            barchart category=make  
                    response=count 
                    /group=type 
                     groupdisplay=stack;
        discretelegend "carmodels";
        endlayout;
    endgraph;
    end;
run;

proc sgrender data=cars template=barchart sganno=annodata;
run;



Why do you define a variable named TEXTCOLOR and then assign values to a variable named COLOR that you never defined?

Don't need annotated dataset, just add segmentlabel=1 as an option of barchart statement. BTW, if you replace layout lattice with layout overlay, the graph would be better.

The capability I´m looking fore is to combine any textcolor with any background color in order to always garantee high contrast for mitigate colorblindness. Ypu have pointed towards things that remains from the code that works gchart, It´s not possible to convert my graphs to gchart.

It is to much work or not possible to convert all my graphs to gchart to be able to deliver graphs with high contrast or apply to https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/

The code has been adjusted concerning TEXTCOLOR.

Instead of annotation can you use a text statement?
